# extract each element in a list using list comprehension

Tags: haskell

I am really new to haskell sorry if this is a relatively easy

I have the following Tree

```
data Tree a =
    Branch a [Tree a]
  | Finish a
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and I want to write a function  **foldTree :: ([a] -> a) -> Tree a -> a** that replaces all the Finish node in the tree with just the data (a) and all Branch node with a call to f such that **f :: ([a] -> a)**

Here is my attempt

```
foldTree :: ([a] -> a) -> Tree a -> a
foldTree f (Finish a) = a
foldTree f (Branch a tree) =  f [foldTree f tree]
```

Right now in my Branch, the tree in f [ foldTree f tree ]  is still a list. How do I extract every element out of tree and apply f to each element?

Comment: `foldTree f tree` won't typecheck.  Did you instead want to fold each subtree?  You can use `map` for that as `foldTree f (Branch a tree) = f (a : map (foldTree f) tree)`.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I am unclear. I did intend to fold the subtree. Thanks for your suggestion, it compiles!

Comment: It seems `Finish a` serves no purpose - it is the same as `Branch a []`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foldTree f (Branch a tree) = ...
```

here we have the following types:

```
   f :: [a] -> a
   a :: a
   tree :: [Tree a]
```

We also have

```
   foldTree f :: Tree a -> a
```

which we obviously need to feed the contents of `tree` somehow, it's the only function that can consume `Tree`s. How? Well, let's call `Tree a` simply `b`, then we need something that takes a function `b -> a` and a `[b]` list, and gives us something else. Perhaps [hoogle knows about such a thing](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28b+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+[b]+-%3E+c)? Turns out it does.

```
map :: (b -> a) -> [b] -> [a]
```

i.e. in our case

```
map :: (Tree a -> a) -> [Tree a] -> [a]
```

therefore

```
map (foldTree f) :: [Tree a] -> [a]
```

and

```
map (foldTree f) tree :: [a]
```

now we're almost done: you could feed this right to `f`, but wait... we also still have `a`! Perhaps you want to prepend that first.

```
foldTree f (Branch a tree) = f $ a : map (foldTree f) tree
```

Comment: If you really want to use a list comprehension, you can instead do `f $ a : [foldTree f t | t <- tree]`